# problems using Ansible to run docker tasks on OS X

Tags: macos, docker, ansible

I am just trying to tell Ansible to build a docker image on my OS X machine and this is the error I get:

```
$ ansible-playbook main.yml

PLAY [localhost] **************************************************************

GATHERING FACTS ***************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK: [Build docker image from dockerfiles] ***********************************
failed: [localhost] => {"changed": false, "failed": true}
msg: ConnectionError(ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', error(2, 'No such file or directory')),)

FATAL: all hosts have already failed -- aborting

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************
           to retry, use: --limit @/Users/ronny/main.retry

localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1
```

This is the main.yml file I am using:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local

  tasks:
        - name: Build docker image from dockerfiles
          docker_image:
            name: testimage
            path: test
            state: build
```

My Dockerfile:

```
# Build an example Docker container image. 
FROM busybox 
MAINTAINER Jeff Geerling <geerlingguy@mac.com>

# Run a command when the container starts. 
CMD ["/bin/true”]”
```

My docker file is located in **cookbook/test/Dockerfile**

And the main.yml file is located in **cookbook/main.yml**

I'm running this on OS X.

I am totally lost at this point and any help would be very appreciated.

**edit:**

In response to Nathanial's request that I use -vvvv I get the following error:

(this is where the path is set to the subdirectory "test")

```
TASK: [Build docker image from dockerfiles] ***********************************
<localhost> ESTABLISH CONNECTION FOR USER: ronny
<localhost> REMOTE_MODULE docker_image name=test state=build path=test
<localhost> EXEC ssh -C -tt -vvv -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o ControlPath="/Users/ronny/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-%h-%p-%r" -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o ConnectTimeout=10 localhost /bin/sh -c 'mkdir -p $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1433079033.35-4833710313724 && chmod a+rx $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1433079033.35-4833710313724 && echo $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1433079033.35-4833710313724'
<localhost> PUT /var/folders/s1/g6kswg952gvg5df6wld173480000gn/T/tmp3g0PIz TO /Users/ronny/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1433079033.35-4833710313724/docker_image
<localhost> EXEC ssh -C -tt -vvv -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o ControlPath="/Users/ronny/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-%h-%p-%r" -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o ConnectTimeout=10 localhost /bin/sh -c 'LANG=en_US.UTF-8 LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8 /usr/bin/python /Users/ronny/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1433079033.35-4833710313724/docker_image; rm -rf /Users/ronny/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1433079033.35-4833710313724/ >/dev/null 2>&1'
failed: [localhost] => {"failed": true, "parsed": false}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ronny/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1433079033.35-4833710313724/docker_image", line 1852, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/ronny/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1433079033.35-4833710313724/docker_image", line 235, in main
    image_id = manager.build()
  File "/Users/ronny/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1433079033.35-4833710313724/docker_image", line 140, in build
    stream = self.client.build(self.path, tag=':'.join([self.name, self.tag]), nocache=self.nocache, rm=True, stream=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/docker/client.py", line 319, in build
    raise TypeError("You must specify a directory to build in path")
TypeError: You must specify a directory to build in path
OpenSSH_6.2p2, OSSLShim 0.9.8r 8 Dec 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug1: auto-mux: Trying existing master
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug2: mux_client_hello_exchange: master version 4
debug3: mux_client_forwards: request forwardings: 0 local, 0 remote
debug3: mux_client_request_session: entering
debug3: mux_client_request_alive: entering
debug3: mux_client_request_alive: done pid = 78798
debug3: mux_client_request_session: session request sent
debug1: mux_client_request_session: master session id: 2
debug3: mux_client_read_packet: read header failed: Broken pipe
debug2: Received exit status from master 0
Shared connection to localhost closed.


FATAL: all hosts have already failed -- aborting

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************
           to retry, use: --limit @/Users/ronny/main.retry

localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1
```

**In response to the above error**, I tried giving the full path to the build directory where Dockerfile is located

```
path: "/Users/ronny/projects/dockers/tutorial/ansibledocker/test”
```

then I got:

```
TASK: [Build docker image from dockerfiles] ***********************************
<localhost> ESTABLISH CONNECTION FOR USER: ronny
<localhost> REMOTE_MODULE docker_image name=test state=build path=/Users/ronny/projects/dockers/tutorial/ansibledocker/test
<localhost> EXEC ssh -C -tt -vvv -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o ControlPath="/Users/ronny/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-%h-%p-%r" -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o ConnectTimeout=10 localhost /bin/sh -c 'mkdir -p $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1433079137.87-213359153110012 && chmod a+rx $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1433079137.87-213359153110012 && echo $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1433079137.87-213359153110012'
<localhost> PUT /var/folders/s1/g6kswg952gvg5df6wld173480000gn/T/tmplH4Lln TO /Users/ronny/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1433079137.87-213359153110012/docker_image
<localhost> EXEC ssh -C -tt -vvv -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o ControlPath="/Users/ronny/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-%h-%p-%r" -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o ConnectTimeout=10 localhost /bin/sh -c 'LANG=en_US.UTF-8 LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8 /usr/bin/python /Users/ronny/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1433079137.87-213359153110012/docker_image; rm -rf /Users/ronny/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1433079137.87-213359153110012/ >/dev/null 2>&1'
failed: [localhost] => {"changed": false, "failed": true}
msg: ConnectionError(ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', error(2, 'No such file or directory')),)

FATAL: all hosts have already failed -- aborting

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************
           to retry, use: --limit @/Users/ronny/main.retry

localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1
```

*edit #2*

OK, I tried doing something different.  instead of building an image, I tried to simply start one.  After diggin in lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/modules/core/cloud/docker/docker.py I noticed that in  class DockerManager.init around line 558, they set a few environment variables:

```
env_host = os.getenv('DOCKER_HOST')
env_docker_verify = os.getenv('DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY')
env_cert_path = os.getenv('DOCKER_CERT_PATH')
env_docker_hostname = os.getenv('DOCKER_TLS_HOSTNAME')
```

So I spat out those values into a log file, and lo and behold, none of them were being set.

Then when I set them directly in main.yml:

```
- name: start container
      docker:
        name: mydata
        image: busybox
        state: present
      environment:
        DOCKER_HOST: tcp://192.168.59.103:2376
        DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY: 1
        DOCKER_CERT_PATH: /Users/ronny/.boot2docker/certs/boot2docker-vm
        DOCKER_TLS_HOSTNAME: boot2docker
```

I was able to successfully start a container!

However, this method did not work with my initial issue, which is to build a docker image.

Digging further in docker_image.py I noticed that it breaks down around line 188 (I say "around" because I have logging breaks so I don't know the exact line) where it has the following code:

```
   images = self.client.images()
```

so more digging and I see that self.client is checking out the docker_url at `'unix://var/run/docker.sock'`

but over at this [link](https://forums.docker.com/t/docker-osx-var-run-docker-sock-file-missing/623) I see that /var/run/docker.sock does not exist on OS X, instead one reply said that

> /var/run/docker.sock will not be on your OSX filesystem - the Docker
>   daemon is running inside the boot2docker VM - and that's where the
>   unix socket is.
>
> That serial file is also not related to the docker socket.
>
> oyu need to talk to the TCP socket specified in the DOCKER_HOST env.

now I tried setting docker_url to the DOCKER_HOST URL, as the description for this modules says:

> docker_url:
>       description:
>         - URL of docker host to issue commands to
>       required: false
>       default: unix://var/run/docker.sock
>       aliases: []

but when I set it to the DOCKER_HOST address, I got an error.

Here is main.yml

```
   - name: Build docker image from dockerfiles 
          docker_image:
            name: testimage 
#            path: test
            path: /Users/ronny/projects/dockers/tutorial/ansibledocker/test
            state: build
            docker_url: 192.168.59.103:2376
```

and here is the error:

```
failed: [localhost] => {"changed": false, "failed": true}
msg: ConnectionError(ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', BadStatusLine('\x15\x03\x01\x00\x02\x02\n',)),)

FATAL: all hosts have already failed -- aborting

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************
           to retry, use: --limit @/Users/ronny/main.retry

localhost                  : ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1
```

Any ideas?

Comment: are you using something like bot2docker to run the images in a vm? Docker wont run on MacOS.

Comment: show me the sample of  `Dockerfile`,

Comment: @BMW-    I edited my question above so you can see the Dockerfile

Comment: @errata - yes, I am using boot2docker

Comment: Run `ansible-playbook` with `-vvv` so you can see the actual command that's producing the error.

Comment: @NathanielWaisbrot - I edited the question to reflect the results that you asked for.

Comment: Your new `path` line contains a curly double-quote (`0xe2809d`) instead of a normal double-quote (`0x22`).

Comment: The quotes I used are the same quotes I use for other ansible path related settings, and I haven't had problems.  In any case, I switched to the single quote and it didn't help.

Comment: I am having this issue with any docker_image module command on OSX. for example: `- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
  - name: remove image
    docker_image: name="my/app" state=absent` 
this works in linux (it should work anywhere) but not OSX with boot2docker. It yields the following error: `ConnectionError(ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', error(2, 'No such file or directory')),)`

Comment: [verbose output from OSX](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=iw6ZW21s)
[verbose output from Ubuntu](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=rVifzfSh)

Comment: @JohnSteel  Yeah, thanks for writing that, that's my experience too.

Comment: @ron Now that I know I'm not alone, I've gone ahead and [opened a ticket on github](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-modules-core/issues/1450)

Answer (score 1):

Your first configuration is almost "ok", two things need change

```
tasks: ...
  path: ./test
  state: present
```

the root directory to the ansible in your case is where your main.yml file is located.

```
cookbook/
├── main.yml
└── test
    └── Dockerfile
```

So the content of the main.yml stay this

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local

  tasks:
  - name: Build docker image from dockerfiles
    docker_image:
      name: testimage
      path: ./test
      state: present
```

The **state** needs to be **present** accord [doc](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/docker_image_module.html#options)

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround you can use a proxy, "socat-container" which routes your request from a tcp address to the unix socket.
Take a look at this [page](http://blog.sequenceiq.com/blog/2014/10/17/boot2docker-tls-workaround/).
The port 2376 on boot2docker just works with ipv6 and not ipv4 (I found no way to change this, I didn't dig deeper into the problem and don't like the idea to make changes to the boot2docker VM).
I also added a NAT Translation in VirtualBox for my localhost(ansible inventory localhost)

Be careful with ansible and docker-py

You need:

- ansible 1.9.2
- docker_api_version: 1.18

works for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to build docker images with Ansible, I would suggest you to take a look at [Ansible Container](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-container/), which is an open source project from Ansible, specifically focusing on building docker images.

Ansible Container enables you to use existing/own Ansible roles, to build docker images.

Answer (score -1):

If you get this error when using docker for mac (beta), you might have forgotten to install docker on your remote server.

Comment: This was the issue I had that led to this.